# How to add alternate colors to rows in Jface tableviewer

Tags: swt, jface

I am using a Jface table viewer with `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` for multiline rows, now I want to add alternate colors to the rows. I tried using colLabelProvider, but it is overwriting `OwnerDrawLabelProvider`. How do I achieve both?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` you will have to do this in your provider. You can fill the cell background in the `erase` method using something like:

```java
@Override
protected void erase(Event event, Object element)
{
  Table table = (Table)event.widget;
  TableItem item = (TableItem)event.item;

  int row = table.indexOf(item);

  Color color;
  if ((row & 1) == 0)
    color = event.gc.getDevice().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN);
  else
    color = event.gc.getDevice().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);

  event.gc.setBackground(color);

  event.gc.fillRectangle(event.x, event.y, event.width, event.height);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thankyou

Comment: How do I change the font size using the same?

Comment: That is a different question, please ask a new question.